# MacTeX-2015, TeXShop, Run Macro/Applescript/Bibliography and receive error message: "### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.etc"

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, mactex, texshop, eps

Novice user here.

Use Mac Os El Capitan, MacTex-2015, TexShop;

Publisher does not support pidflatex and requires figures to be in EPS;

Typeset settings: LaTeX, TeX and DVI;

Bibliography: Natbib.

Question: When I use macro/Applescript/Bibliography I receive the error message below, even though all the citations and figures in the text, and references at the end seem to compile with no problem (sometimes I need to repeat the command.)

However, when publisher's system compiles the files to pdf, citations in the text appears as question marks.

I have some other issues like "Overfull \hbox (48.83583pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 83--83
\OT1/bch/m/n/9 sis. [][][][]| " but I believe they are not related.

[image]

[image]

In the log file:

```
log file error: 
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
```

Not sure whether "empty hook" is a sign of error:

```
\@emptytoks=\toks14
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 664.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 664.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 664.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 664.
```

Comment: Have you fixed the error that arises when your in `dvips`? Are there error and/or warning messages in the .log and .blg files? Have you transmitted the bbl file to the publisher, or have you tried copying and pasting its contents into the main tex file?

Comment: No problem solved. Added the log file error in the main question. I don't find any problem in .blg file. All extensions are transferred to the publisher. I haven't copy paste them in the main text.

Comment: Hi are you around to chat about this?

Comment: @Alan Munn Sure, I am available.

Comment: See if you can get to this room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36193/discussion-between-alan-and-doruk

Comment: It says I need 20 points to talk in the chat room :( Still, I can read what you write.
Any other methods of communication?

Comment: Try leaving the room and re-entering. You now have enough reputation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36194/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-doruk-iris).

Comment: Can we try to open a new room. I have 21 points, but the chat room still warns me that I should have 20 points.

Comment: Maybe the system generate chat room will work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by a bug in the Applescript that is designed to automate bibliography creation in TeXShop.  I suspect that nobody uses it much any more, which is why the problem has gone unnoticed.

A better way to automate bibliography and reference resolution is to use one of the the `latexmk` engines provided with TeXShop.

If you don't have the `latexmk` Engine installed, go to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/` and move the `.engine` files from the `Inactive/Latexmk` folder to the `Engines` folder.

Restart TeXShop, and the new engines should appear in the pulldown menu beside the Typeset button in the document window.  If you're using `latex+dvips` as your usual engine, then use `latexmk` instead.  You can do this automatically by adding the line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk
```

This will resolve all references, and only runs `bibtex` when there are changes.